# Remove a specific WebSocket from array of web sockets

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, vapor

I have this array of tuples:

```
private var clientsConnections = [ (String,[WebSocket]) ]()
```

**String**: the room's ID

**[WebSocket]**: websockets of the users in that room

I am trying to close the connection of a specific WebSocket inside a room, let's say when a user exit the room, and remove that WebSocket from my array.
The problem I have is that WebSocket is not convertible to AnyHashable.

What I've tried:

```
ws.onClose.whenComplete { _ in
  for i in 0..<clientsConnections.count {
     if clientsConnections[i].0 == roomID {
       if let socketIndex = clientsConnections[i].1.firstIndex(where: {$0 == ws}) {
          clientsConnections[i].1.remove(at: socketIndex)
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Getting this: (right below the statement: "{ $0 == ws }"

> 'WebSocket' is not convertible to 'AnyHashable'

Comment: Why aren't you removing the web socket from your clientsConnections array? What does accessing tuple.1 do for you since it's local to the for loop?

Comment: @Kwright02 that's true, but it's just an example, the issue still remains even after accessing the original array instead of a local element.

Comment: Well, can I see your original code? Because the behavior IS different between the local scope and the private var on the class you're using. Also, what exactly is tuple.<number>

Comment: @Kwright02 I've edited the code above and the content of the post (the error message changed).
tuple.0 = the room's id,
tuple.1 = the websocket array

Comment: Are you doing some kind of type conversion on your ws variable?

Comment: Maybe you should work with a custom type consisting of user and web socket

Comment: @Kwright02 I am not

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's a good idea, I will definitely go there if there isn't a "quick fix" to it.
but generally, web sockets aren't meant to be compared with one another? how do you usually remove a WebSocket from an array of WebSockets?

Comment: take a look at awesomews vapor library as a reference, it is implemented there

Answer (score 1):

I would use a **dictionary**; `WebSocket` doesn't have to conform to `Hashable` if you're referencing it with a key.

I've implemented it [here](https://github.com/briannadoubt/Affirmate/blob/main/AffirmateServer/Sources/AffirmateServer/Chat/ChatWebSocketClients.swift#L43) in a side project I've been putting together with Swift.

Here's a cherry-picked implementation:

```swift
actor ChatWebSocketManager: WebSocketManager {
    var clients: ChatWebSocketClients

    init(eventLoop: EventLoop) {
        clients = ChatWebSocketClients(eventLoop: eventLoop)
    }

    func connect(_ request: Request, _ webSocket: WebSocket) {
        webSocket.onBinary { webSocket, buffer async -> () in
            // Handle data from client connection on server
        }
    }
}

actor ChatWebSocketClients {
    var storage: [UUID: ChatWebSocketClient] // <~ Money shot
    var eventLoop: EventLoop

    init(eventLoop: EventLoop, clients: [UUID: ChatWebSocketClient] = [:]) {
        self.eventLoop = eventLoop
        storage = clients
    }

    deinit {
        let futures = self.storage.values
            .map {
                $0.socket.close()
            }
        do {
            try self.eventLoop.flatten(futures).wait()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to flatten WebSocket futures:", error)
            assertionFailure("Failed to flatten WebSocket futures")
        }
    }
    
    func active() -> [UUID: ChatWebSocketClient] {
        storage.filter({ !$0.value.socket.isClosed })
    }

    func add(_ client: ChatWebSocketClient) throws {
        storage[client.id] = client
    }

    func remove(clientId: UUID) {
        storage.removeValue(forKey: clientId)
    }

    func getConnectedClients(for chatId: UUID) -> [UUID: ChatWebSocketClient] {
        active().filter({ $0.value.chatId == chatId })
    }
}

open class ChatWebSocketClient {
    open var id: UUID
    open var userId: UUID
    open var chatId: UUID
    open var socket: WebSocket
    
    required public init(id: UUID, userId: UUID, chatId: UUID, socket: WebSocket) {
        self.id = id
        self.userId = userId
        self.chatId = chatId
        self.socket = socket
    }
}
```

Then in the `configure.swift` file:

```swift
public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
    // Configure Database
    // ...

    // Register Routes
    // ...

    // Set up WebSocket endpoint
    let chatWebSocketManager = ChatWebSocketManager(eventLoop: app.eventLoopGroup.next())
    app
        .grouped(SessionToken.authenticator(), SessionToken.guardMiddleware())
        .webSocket("chats", ":chatId") { request, webSocket async in
            await chatWebSocketManager.connect(request, webSocket)
        }
}
```